# Excel-VBA: Unable to Insert Line Breaks

Tags: excel, vba, newline

I need to insert lines in a cell, but I am unable to insert line breaks.

For example :

> line1
>
> line2
>
> line3

With VBA code :

```
             Ws.Cells(i, 2) = line1 & line2 & line3
```

I get :

> line1 line2 line3

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: are `line1`, `line2`, `line3` strings? without linebreaks naturally in them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "line1" & vbnewline & "line2" & vbnewline & "line3"
```

or

```
Ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "line1" & vbCrLf & "line2" & vbCrLf & "line3"
```

**EDIT**: Inserted quotes as mentioned in my comments.

Comment: If line1 is a text then put them in quotes like "line1" & vbnewline & "line2" & vbnewline & "line3"

Answer (score 3):

I have tested a few combinations and here are the results:

```
cell(a,b) = line1 & vbCrLf & line2
```

result:
line1**
line2

```
cell(a,b) = line1 & vbCr & line2
```

result:
line1line2

```
cells(a,b) = line1 & vbLf & line2
```

result:
line1
line2

In the above results the * denotes a blank space (I don't know why), so the vbCrLf is not recommended when you want to center the cell content horizontally. My preference goes for vbLf.

Answer (score 0):

Linebreaks in VBA are `vbCrLf` and you can concatenate them with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ws.Cells(i, 2) = line1 & line2 & Chr(10) & line3
```

[As per this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900916/insert-line-break-in-wrapped-cell-through-vba-code)

Answer (score -2):

FYI, you can prevent coding typos by using an easier-to-type variable name.

```
bx = vbCrLf

textstring = "Hello everybody!" & bx & "This is my second line!"
```

Comment: That would make your code harder to read since you are going against what the reader would expect, thus not recommended at all.