# Data URI default charset

Tags: character-encoding, uri, source-maps, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

Is there a default charset for data URIs? I read [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) but I don't see one.

For instance, if I have a data URI for a source map which I expect to be reliably interpreted across browsers, is it OK to omit the charset?

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJza...
```

vs

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJza...
```

I see in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/753) that people have had problems using Chinese characters in source-mapped files without an explicit `charset=utf-8`. So if there is a default (or, at least, if we could expect browsers to have chosen one), it doesn't seem like `utf-8` is the one...

Comment: This doesn't relate to the data URI itself but the interpretation of the data. There is a standard for JSON, which is UTF-8 only, but that is a relatively recent change from the standard that it must be one of several Unicode encodings that are easily distinguished in the context of valid JSON.  So, charset on an application/json MIME type is unnecessary if you assume compliance with past or present JSON standards. If the JSON is non-standard, I suggest converting it as close to the source as possible (and filing a bug report if applicable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 2397 § 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397#section-2), **a data URI without a specified `charset` defaults to `US-ASCII`**. Because [every Base64-encoded URI uses only ASCII characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Encoding_data_into_base64_format). Moreover, “all US‑ASCII strings become valid UTF‑8” which means there’s “decent backwards compatibility in many cases”.<sup>1</sup>

Nevertheless, UTF-8 implementation remains uneven in 2019. Because of that – and because there is little cost to explicitly calling the `charset` to already-user-unfriendly data URIs – it’s probably not a bad idea to **include `charset=utf-8` in your sourcemap URIs** in order to keep them reliably interpreted across browsers.

---

1. Arjun Chaudhary’s answer to [Is there a drastic difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22404493/#22404874).