# How does C distinguish between a byte long character and a 2 byte long character?

Tags: c, linux, bash, io, kernel

I have this sample code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    printf("%li\n",sizeof(char));
    char mytext[20];
    read(1,mytext,3);
    printf("%s",mytext);
    return 0;
}
```

First run:

```
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~$ ./a.out 
1
pp
pp
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~$
```

Well I think this is all expected as p is 1 byte long character defined in ASCII and I am reading 3 bytes. (2 p's and Line break) In the terminal, again I see 2 characters.

Now let's try with a character that is 2 bytes long:

```
koray@koray-VirtualBox:~$ ./a.out 
1
ğ
ğ
```

What I do not understand is, when I send the character 'ğ' to the memory pointed by mytext variable, 16 bits are written to that area. As 'ğ' is 11000100:10011110 in utf-8, these bytes are written.

My question is, when printing back to the standard out, how does C (or should I say the kernel?) know that, it should read 2 bytes and interpret as 1 character instead of 2 1-byte characters?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How does that help me?

Comment: It doesn't, really.  UTF-8 platforms tend to implement a `w_char`

Comment: Two different sets of functions (for functions like printf) are used in C, one for ASCII, the other for UNICODE. Microsoft has an extension using <tchar.h> where a program can use the same names, like TCHAR instead of char (ASCII) or WCHAR / wchar_t / unsigned short (UNICODE), _tprintf(), _T("...") for string literals, ... , that are either ASCII or UNICODE depending on project settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't interpret it. Your program reads 2 bytes and outputs same 2 bytes without caring about what characters (or anything else) they are.

Your terminal encodes your input and reinterprets your output back as the same two byte character.

Comment: So if I had a dumb terminal, it could interpret it as 2 8 bit characters?

Comment: But how does the terminal know that that is a 2 byte character?

Comment: It looks at the first bit. Since it's set to 1, the terminal (or whatever is reading the string) knows it's not ascii, and that it containt 2 bytes or more.

It will know if it's more by the content of the other bits.

Comment: Locale, terminal configuration, guessing. Think what happens when you output w/o further processing those bytes, hardcoded in your app. E.g. you may play with Konsole's profile encoding setting to display various characters/junk repeatedly running that simple app, by interpreting output differently.

Answer (score 3):

Ascii range from 0 to 127. The first 128 characters of Unicode are the ascii caracters.

The first bit will tell if your character is in the 0-127 range or above it. If it's 1, it means it is unicode and 16 bits will be considered (or even more).

This question is closely related to: [What's the difference between ASCII and Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/difference-between-ascii-and-unicode)

Comment: You could also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences

Comment: Which process is looking at the first bit to determine the range? bash? What if I redirect the standard out to a file with > somefile.txt

Comment: Whatever is rendering the string will have to do this check. In your case, that was the terminal.

Comment: I see, so if I write the bytes to a text file, whatever process that opens it needs to check it?

Comment: Absolutely. Also, unicode is not always 2 bytes. Anything decoding it need to keep checking every character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78463/discussion-between-rsinohara-and-koray-tugay).

Comment: @KorayTugay All Unicode codepoints are numbered between 0 and less than 2^21 (0x10ffff). So, a 21 bit number is enough. Unicode has several encodings that spread those bits into one or more code-units in different ways. UTF-32 is simple: four bytes for any codepoints. UTF-8 seems to be the one you are using because its code-unit is one byte. So, think about how to put codepoints into one or more code-units with common codepoints in fewer code-units than less common codepoints. [Scroll down to Table 3-6](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404).