# C# User Input Into Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

This is probably a very ridiculous question but I can't figure out how to import the user's input into a byte array. Since user input is always in a string format a conversation will be needed, however the numbers he entered must be the same in the array. For example:

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
string text = Console.ReadLine();

/* Lets assume the user entered 22, 101, 1
   How would I get those exact numbers in byte[]
*/

byte[] arr = new Byte[] {text};
```

UPDATED: what I am looking to get is

```
byte[] arr = new Byte[] {22, 101, 1};
```

Comment: are you looking for the array to contain the integers 22,101,1 or ascii equivalent bytes to the bytes of 22.  Which would be 50,50 (for "22")  http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: What I am actually looking to get is byte[] arr = new Byte[] {22, 101, 1};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
string text = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] byteArrayUTF= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text);
byte[] byteArrayASCII= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (text);
```

You can find a better explanation here for the difference between [UTF8 and ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode)

> Unicode is a superset of ASCII, and the numbers 0–128 have the same
>   meaning in ASCII as they have in Unicode.

(From the updates)I think You are actually looking for converting the input string (comma separated values ) into an array of bytes. if so you can use thm Like the following:

```
 string text = Console.ReadLine();
 byte[] byteArr = text.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your solution worked great, thank you very much. I was wondering if it is possible to modify byte[] byteArr = text.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x)).ToArray(); So that it will accept input strings with + signs. For example, 1+2, 3+6, 33+2 ?

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers explain how to convert a `string` to a `byte[]`,
I believe what you really want is to get the numbers into a `byte[]`

```
var input = "22, 101, 1";
var numbers = input.Split(',')
                   .Select(p => byte.Parse(p));
```

This will split the input at every `,` and convert each part to an integer.

Comment: @un-lucky or, ya know, you could just fix it yourself. This is a community site, anyone can edit any post.

Answer (score 1):

This uses [LINQ-to-Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) to "pipeline" from a string to an array of strings to a sequence of bytes to an array of bytes:

```
var arr = text
    .Split(',')
    .Select(digits => Byte.Parse(digits))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetBytes function to convert strings into bytes.

```
byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
byte[] arr = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)
byte[] arr = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text)
```

If you are looking for a specific encoding type you can use the following to convert from other standard encoding types into what .NET provides.

```
byte[] arr = GetStringEncoding(StringEncodingType.CHARSET_UTF_16BE_CODEPAGE).GetBytes(text);

public static Encoding GetStringEncoding(StringEncodingType type)
        {
             switch (type)
            {
                case StringEncodingType.ASCII:
                    return Encoding.ASCII;
                case StringEncodingType.Unicode:
                    return Encoding.Unicode;
                    //return Encoding.UTF7;
                case StringEncodingType.UTF8:
                    return Encoding.UTF8;
                //case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_UTF_16LE_CODEPAGE:// 1200, same as unicode
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_UTF_16BE_CODEPAGE:// 1201,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE:// 12000,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_UTF_32BE_CODEPAGE:// 12001,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_WINDOWS_1251_CODEPAGE:// 1251,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_WINDOWS_1252_CODEPAGE:// 1252,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_WINDOWS_1253_CODEPAGE:// 1253,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_WINDOWS_1255_CODEPAGE:// 1255,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_2022_JP_CODEPAGE:// 50220,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_2022_CN_CODEPAGE:// 50227,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_2022_KR_CODEPAGE:// 50225,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_8859_5_CODEPAGE:// 28595,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_8859_7_CODEPAGE:// 28597,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_ISO_8859_8_CODEPAGE:// 28598,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_BIG5_CODEPAGE:// 950,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_GB18030_CODEPAGE:// 54936,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_EUC_JP_CODEPAGE:// 20932,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_EUC_KR_CODEPAGE:// 51949,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_SHIFT_JIS_CODEPAGE:// 932,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_IBM855_CODEPAGE:// 855,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_IBM866_CODEPAGE:// 866,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_KOI8_R_CODEPAGE:// 20866,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_MACCYRILLIC_CODEPAGE:// 10007,
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_HZ_GB_2312_CODEPAGE:// 52936,
                //case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_X_ISO_10646_UCS_4_3412_CODEPAGE:// 12000, same as CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE
                //case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_X_ISO_10646_UCS_4_2143_CODEPAGE:// 12000, same as CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE
                case StringEncodingType.CHARSET_WINDOWS_874_CODEPAGE:// 874
                    return Encoding.GetEncoding((int)type);
                default:
                    throw new System.NotSupportedException("Error Missing String Encoding Type:" + type.ToString());
            }
        }



public enum StringEncodingType // the numbers are the codepage
    {
        Unknown = -1,
        ASCII = 20127,
        Unicode = 1200,
        UTF8 = 65001,
        //CHARSET_UTF_16LE_CODEPAGE = 1200,  same as unicode
        CHARSET_UTF_16BE_CODEPAGE = 1201,
        CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE = 12000,
        CHARSET_UTF_32BE_CODEPAGE = 12001,
        CHARSET_WINDOWS_1251_CODEPAGE = 1251,
        CHARSET_WINDOWS_1252_CODEPAGE = 1252,
        CHARSET_WINDOWS_1253_CODEPAGE = 1253,
        CHARSET_WINDOWS_1255_CODEPAGE = 1255,
        CHARSET_ISO_2022_JP_CODEPAGE = 50220,
        CHARSET_ISO_2022_CN_CODEPAGE = 50227,
        CHARSET_ISO_2022_KR_CODEPAGE = 50225,
        CHARSET_ISO_8859_5_CODEPAGE = 28595,
        CHARSET_ISO_8859_7_CODEPAGE = 28597,
        CHARSET_ISO_8859_8_CODEPAGE = 28598,
        CHARSET_BIG5_CODEPAGE = 950,
        CHARSET_GB18030_CODEPAGE = 54936,
        CHARSET_EUC_JP_CODEPAGE = 20932,
        CHARSET_EUC_KR_CODEPAGE = 51949,
        CHARSET_SHIFT_JIS_CODEPAGE = 932,
        CHARSET_IBM855_CODEPAGE = 855,
        CHARSET_IBM866_CODEPAGE = 866,
        CHARSET_KOI8_R_CODEPAGE = 20866,
        CHARSET_MACCYRILLIC_CODEPAGE = 10007,
        CHARSET_HZ_GB_2312_CODEPAGE = 52936,
        //CHARSET_X_ISO_10646_UCS_4_3412_CODEPAGE = 12000, same as CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE
        //CHARSET_X_ISO_10646_UCS_4_2143_CODEPAGE = 12000, same as CHARSET_UTF_32LE_CODEPAGE
        CHARSET_WINDOWS_874_CODEPAGE = 874
    }
```