# Persian font encoding in m-files on Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Trying to type `Persian` in `m-files` caused to face an interesting encoding problem. Persian characters are not supported when a `m-file` running. for more information see the following gif:

[image]

I'm wondering different encoding between `command window` and `m-file`.
Initial guess was that the `m-files` works with [ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode) encoding while the `command window` use [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode) instead. I've tried to solve it myself but I prefer to ask here maybe someone faced this error on his/her project.