# Why w/cout does not support string U/u prefixes?

Tags: c++, string, iostream, cout

I have the following code inspired by one of the SO questions:

```
int main()
{
    wcout << "\n\n 1- Test normal string with wcout \n";
    wcout << u8"\n 2- Test (u8) string with wcout  \n";
    wcout << u"\n 3- Test (u) string with wcout \n";
    wcout << U"\n 4- Test (U) string with wcout \n";
    wcout << L"\n 5- Test (L) string with wcout \n\n"; 
}
```

which results in:

[image: Output]

`cout` has similar output.

I understand from the answer on [*this post*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354126/c-literals-and-unicode) that w/cout does not support the string U/u prefixes, or exactly as mentioned:

> Meanwhile `std::cout's` class has no special `<<` overload for `const char16_t*`, `const char32_t*` and `const wchar_t*`, hence it will match
>   `<<`'s overload for printing pointers.

My questions are:

1- Why it does not support these types? Isn't it a strange for a language not to support its own types?
2- Are there any known plans to add such support in the seen future?

I know that iostream is a library, but, practically, it is still part of the language.

Comment: Encoding and (wide) character representation are orthogonal things. IMO that's answered in the question you linked.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand that there is ambiguity for an `u8""` string literal as it maps to `const char[]` which has no associated encoding, but `u""` maps to `const char16_t[]` and `U""` maps to `const char32_t[]` which according to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) imply UTF-16 / UTF-32 encoding.

Comment: @zett42 Well, that's why I've been upvoting that question (I have some problems understanding that in detail mayself ;-) ).

Answer (score 0):

The usual answer to standard library omissions applies: nobody proposed to add overloads for `char16_t const*` or `char32_t`. The proposal to add the character types ([N2249](http://wg21.link/n2249)) did not contain the relevant library parts. In particular, it didn't add overloads for

```
template <typename charT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, Traits>& std::operator<< (std::basic_ostream<charT, Traits>&, char16_t const*);
template <typename charT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, Traits>& std::operator<< (std::basic_ostream<charT, Traits>&, char32_t const*);
```

As there is an overload of these operator taking `void const*` the address of the pointer is printed. As the new character types are kind of pointless (at least, from my point of view: just use UTF8) I doubt there is anybody interested in creating a proposal.