# why the output displays 3 and not a char in java

Tags: java, unicode, char, ascii, arithmetic-expressions

i would understand why the output is 3 and not a char ('5' unicode character)

```
char c='5';
c = (char) (c - 2);
System.out.println(c);
```

and could you please explain what's the difference beetween code ASCII and unicode character ?

thank you in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ASCII and Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode)

Comment: The subtraction turns the character `'5'` into the character `'3'`. See e.g. [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to understand why.

Comment: What do you mean "not a char"? It's the char `'3'` - it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: A key conceptual difference is that ASCII has one encoding while Unicode has several. Now that you know that, you can forget about ASCII. You are not—and possibly won't ever be—writing code that uses ASCII. XML, HTML, etc use Unicode. Java, .NET, JavaScript, SQL (NCHAR, NVARCHAR) use the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a character. It's a character representing the numeral 3, just as '3' is a character on your keyboard.

When you subtract one from a character, you get the character immediately before that. For example, `'B' - 1 = A`.

You start with the *character* '5' and subtract two, giving the character '3'. If you subtracted 6, you would not get -1, you'd get a random character ('/' I think).

Basically this subtraction works because the *characters* 0 - 9 are stored contiguously.

Answer (score 1):

The output is the `char` `'3'`, not the number `3`.

When you subtract `2` from the char `'5'` and cast the result to `char`, you get the char `'3'`.

The `char` type is a numeric primitive type. Each character has a corresponding integer value between 0 and 2^16-1. The integer value of the character '3' is smaller by 2 than the value of the character '5'.