# CSS \9d005 - what does it means

Tags: css

I am new to the CSS. While reading CSS of a website it is writing as:

```
 .abc:before { content:"\9d005" }
```

I fully understood as:

- .abc  - is the class
- :before - selector inserts something before the content of selected element
- content - used with :before or :after to insert generated content

What to understand what is:

```
\9d005
```

Answer (score 0):

It called **ASCII** code (Unicode).

The general format for a Unicode character inside a string is \000000 to \FFFFFF – a backslash followed by six hexadecimal digits.

Here is a [list of examples](https://unicode-table.com/en/) , and [this conversion tool](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) might be useful.

In CSS, these Unicodes can be only used in `:before` , `:after` and `::marker` CSS pseudo-element.

Comment: they can be also used as content of `::marker` pseudoelement

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan , yup forgot to say that. thank you.

Comment: ASCII and Unicode are not the same. ASCII uses one byte per character, Unicode is much more extensive. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212306/whats-the-difference-between-ascii-and-unicode