# Carriage return in c programming showing different output

Tags: c

**Carriage return** `\r` is used to mark cursor to the start line.But when below code is compiled in turbo c it gives different output than from an online compiler !

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("abcd\r123");
getch();
}
```

**Output:**

```
123d
```

Code used in online compiler :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

     printf("abcd\r123");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

> What is the correct output ? Im confused also whats the reason for
>   that behavior? [In both cases `printf` produces same result !]

Some references that could not help me understand:

[What are carriage return, linefeed, and form feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed)

[What is the difference between a "line feed" and a "carriage return"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return)

Comment: how come that become a duplicate ?

Comment: Can you tell about the OS/platform you are running locally as well as online (if you know).  The most likely explanation for what you see is that `\r` is being intepreted as newline in one place but not the other.

Comment: sure @TimBiegeleisen OS : Windows 7  (locally)..online compiler link : https://ideone.com/fAMDBC

Comment: thank you @TimBiegeleisen would you please tell me whats the correct output ? shall i go with the first one ?

Comment: It's hard to say what is "correct" here.  Cats like eating fish, but fish like eating grass.  Which one is right?  It depends on what you want to really see (i.e. a newline or something else).

Comment: So there is no standard implementation for that.it depends on platform or software ..thank you tim...but still i believe "cats like eating firsh" is correct rather "fish like eating grass" :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Isn't newline in Windows `\r\n`? Sorry if I'm wrong, it's been a while since I've coded for Windows.

Comment: exactly when we use \r\n ..but not when \r alone

Comment: `\n = CR (Carriage Return)` :- new line character in Unix,
`\r = LF (Line Feed)` :- new line character in Mac OS,
`\n\r = CR + LF` :- new line character in Windows,
`(char)13 = \n = CR` :- Same as \n