# export column Values in single Line , Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a column value in my Oracle DB in 2 lines as in below image where line 2 has a space too ( probably they have used "enter" button while inserting the values. Now when i export to excel from Oracle BIP , I get the column values in 2 different cells causing it to row merge.

I have tried to fix this in SQL query like below but didn't work

Replace(Table__100."Description",CHR(10),''),

[image: Multiple Line]

Comment: did you try to replace CHR(13) as well ?

Comment: CHR(13) worked.. Whats the difference between CHR(10)and CHR(13)

Answer (score 0):

The below samples will given an explanation. The below queries when run on sql client gives adjacent output

1. `select 'hello' || chr(10)|| 'world' from dual;`

Output -

`"hello
world"`

2. `select 'hello' || chr(13) || 'world' from dual;`

Output -

`"hello
world"`

3. `select 'hello' || chr(10) || chr(13) || 'world' from dual;`

Output -

```
"hello

world"
```

4. `select 'hello' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'world' from dual;`

Output -

`"hello
world"`

The difference between CHR(10) Line feed character and CHR(13) Carriage return is mentioned in  a previous answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return)

Usually when you press enter in windows, that is a combination of above statement 4.