# why remove "\n","\r","\t" in phalcon？

Tags: php, phalcon

I found that in the muilti-module which is created by phalcon-tool has these code:

```
$application = new Application($di);
echo str_replace(["\n","\r","\t"], '', $application->handle()->getContent());
```

Why remove "\n","\r","\t"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Spangen pointed out, these are the escape sequences for some special 'whitespace' characters.

This link here has more information on them: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Now, an important note: for them to work as intended in PHP, you need to enclose them in double quotes, like: `"\t", "\n"`. Single quotes won't produce the intended effects of these escape sequences: `'\t', '\n'`.

To illustrate this more, you can run this code and see the results. Running it from console like `php myfile.php` might cause some visual glitches, and running it in the browser will need that you view the 'source code'.

```
echo "Let's test... ";
echo "Because no new line characters were added, this sentence will be printed in the same line as the previous phrase.";
echo "\n";
echo "But now a new line was added, by typing \\n enclosed in double quotes.";
echo "\n";
echo "Now, let's add a tab, between the next two words: hello \t there.";
echo "\n";
echo "Now, let's add a carriage return, which will 'force' the 'cursor' in this string to move to the beginning, thus 'splitting' this string into two. Adding it now: \r There, I just added it before this last sentence.";
echo "\n";
echo 'Finally, these special characters will not work as intended if we just enclose the string with single quotes, as done in this string: \n \t \r';
```

This link here has more information on the difference between new lines and carriage returns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747850/466395

---

So yeah, in the original code that you posted, the person removed those special characters using str_replace(), because they tend to produce 'visual glitches' (unintented malformed output) in console.

Comment: Note: sorry if I offered a long explanation of those characters. For a moment I thought you didn't know what they are (is that the case?). But yeah, the _reason_ for the original code you posted is for cleaning up the output.

Comment: Thanks! That makes me learn more. In my project, this code make me   parse html failed, now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is to replace newlines, line feeds and tabs with a single space so that the application's details can be written to STD_OUT as a single line with no wrapping.