# Why does char 0xA change to 0xD + 0xA characters when writing it into a file with a console?

Tags: c++, newline, cout

I used
`std::cout << (char)0xA`
in my C++ code.
Then, I wrote to the console `myProgram.exe > file.txt`.
Next, I opened `file.txt` with A HEX editor and I found `0D 0A` instead of `0A`.

IDK why this happened. Please, help.

[HEX Editor screenshot (look at 0x82 and 0x19B)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8Ap.png)

Comment: One some platforms, the canonical end-of-line is `0D 0A` for a `'\n'`.

Comment: Already resolved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return

Answer (score 4):

The C and C++ Standards both specify that when a stream is open in text mode, sending a `\n` to it will do whatever action is necessary on the target system to advance the file to the next line.  On a Unix system, that simply means outputting a `\n` to a file.  On some record-based systems, it means flushing the current line-output record and advancing to the next one.  On MS-DOS and Windows, it means sending both a `\r` and `\n` to the stream.

Historically, sending a `\r` to a teletype would reset the carriage to the left edge, and sending a `\n` would advance the paper.  Someone realized that while the ability to reset the carriage without advancing paper was useful, having `\n` advance the paper without resetting the carriage was far less so, and thus some devices will respond to `\n` by advancing to the *start* of the next line.  MS-DOS, however, opted to have files stored in a way that would produce meaningful output if sent directly to a printer where `\n` would advance to the current location on the next line, and one would have to send both `\r` and `\n` if one wanted to go to the start of the next line.

Comment: Thanks. I`ll use ofstream next time.

Comment: Should be the same result as long as you are on the same OS.

Comment: MS-DOS inherited the behavior from CP/M.  ASCII at one time required `0D 0A`, but eventually made the `0D` implied if not present.  Apple (AppleDOS, Mac OS) didn't get the memo, and went with `0D` as end-of-line until OS X.

Comment: I opened file.txt with std::ios::binary and it works fine!

Comment: That is correct, in text mode you get the behavior in binary you don't

Comment: @Eljay: Most printers were configurable to treat 0x0D as a command to reset the carriage and advance paper, but would always treat 0x0A as a command to advance paper without resetting the carriage without a configuration option to do otherwise.

Comment: @supercat • plus configuring the number of NUL characters to send after a CRLF so the carriage has enough time to actually return to left side.  Good times.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the magic of end of lines across OS!

The C language originally was developped for Unix systems where the end of line was marked by the single `'\n'` (ASCII code `0x0A`) character.

When it was ported to other systems, it was decided that *seen from the programmer* an end of line will only be a `'\n'`, and that the drivers and the standard library would convert it to the appropriate line ending when the file would be opened in *text* mode.

That convention was later keeped in C++.

As Windows uses `"\r\n"` as an end of line marker, the standard library convert any `'\n'` to the pair `"\r\n"` (ASCII codes `0x0D` and `0x0A`).