# Is it possible to replace a double line break in Excel without using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet in which a column has cells with 2 consecutive line breaks and I would like to replace them with a single line break.

I've actually been able to achieve that using a VBA function:

```
Function ClearLineBreaks(cell As Range) As String
    ClearLineBreaks = Replace(cell.Value, vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)
End Function
```

But I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve the same result using only Excel functions.

Comment: Use _Find and Replace_

Comment: @Storax That would work, but I'm looking for a permanent solution as more cells will be added to that column that will have the same problem.

Comment: What about formulas (`SUBSTITUTE`)then, but this will not work without an extra column?

Comment: @Storax The extra column is not a problem (I know it has to be like that). What would it look like using the ```SUBSTITUTE``` function?

Comment: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),CHAR(10))`

Comment: It works, I was sure I tried it (maybe I used ```CHAR(13)``` instead of ```CHAR(10)```). If you want to put the code as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to help. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return) regarding the difference between new line `CHAR(10)`  and carriage return `CHAR(13)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visits and following @Storax advice, this is what worked for me:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10) & CHAR(10),CHAR(10))
```