# Grep for variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, bioinformatics

I am trying to write a sh script that will open a text file, grep each line in a tsv file, then do various things with the output. I'm stuck on the grepping.

strains_list_test:

```
p1.A2
p1.A3
p1.C5
p1.D11
p1.D2
p8.H2
```

The sh script so far:

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)
STRAINS=$(pwd)/strains_list_test
OUTPUT_DIR=$(pwd)/output

BLAST_FILE=$(pwd)/filtered2.tsv

#this generates fasta files for all strains in input file.
cat $STRAINS | while read strain_name
    do
        echo "strain name is" $strain_name
        grep '$strain_name' $BLAST_FILE | head 
        
    done
```

The output looks like this:

```
strain name is p1.A2
strain name is p1.A3
strain name is p1.C5
strain name is p1.D11
strain name is p1.D2
strain name is p8.H2
```

So in each loop, the grep returns nothing. After searching online for answers I have tried '$strain_name', "$strain_name", "/$strain_name", "${strain_name}" and god knows what else, but to no avail.

The thing is, if I leave out the variable and just do `grep "p8.H2" $BLAST_FILE | head` (for example), I get the correct output. So at least that part works, but something about the way I use the variable as grep input or maybe the line reading is broken... Even though the echo line still prints the variable correctly.

**EDIT:** Multiple people have recommended I use double quotes instead. As I said above, **I have already tried "$strain_name".**

Here's an example TSV file.

```
ProtName p26.C10|protID 58.744 223 83 2 1 216 1 221 1.95e-59 234 100
ProtName p26.C10|protID 38.000 150 68 1 216 340 72 221 6.37e-14 85.5 100
ProtName p8.H2|protID 34.300 207 100 5 101 278 22 221 1.20e-12 81.3 100
ProtName p23.A4|protID 72.002 1718 453 4 340 2029 72 1789 0.0 2511 100
ProtName p23.A4|protID 58.744 223 83 2 1 216 1 221 1.95e-59 234 100
ProtName p23.A4|protID 38.000 150 68 1 216 340 72 221 6.37e-14 85.5 100
ProtName p23.A4|protID 34.300 207 100 5 101 278 22 221 1.20e-12 81.3 100
```

Here is the current code in its entirety.

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)
STRAINS=$(pwd)/strains_list_test
OUTPUT_DIR=$(pwd)/output

BLAST_FILE=$(pwd)/filtered2_sample.tsv

cat $STRAINS | while read strain_name
    do
        echo "strain name is" $strain_name
        grep "$strain_name" $BLAST_FILE | head 
        
    done
echo "testing non-variable grep"
grep "p8.H2" $BLAST_FILE | head
```

**SECOND EDIT:**
I have tried running my code with the bash -x script command to provide a detailed log.
Here is what I get in the test echo lines:
`echo 'strain name is' $'p8.H2\r'`
Maybe the \r is the reason the grep isn't working?. Any ideas on how to fix this?

**THIRD EDIT:**
The grep definitely isn't the issue: I tried this instead:

for strain_name in p1.A2 p1.A3 p1.C5 p1.D11 p8.H2 p1.D2

So it works when I don't read the file and have the strains list directly in the script. I don't really want this for the final version, but this suggests there's something wrong with the way the strains_list_test file is being read. (And no, before you ask, changing the "while read" to "for ... in" alone didn't do it.)

**FOURTH EDIT**
The above code works when I change the strains_list_test file from a column to just p1.A2 p1.A3 p1.C5 p1.D11 p8.H2 p1.D2
So I found a way to do what I wanted to do. However, it's still not clear why the previous version wasn't working.

Comment: Careful sh != bash.  What shebang line do you use at the top of your script?  Bash ou sh?

Comment: Can we assume that tsv is "tab separate values"?  Your sample data does not have tabs (that we can see anyway).  Provide a complete example with a sample blast file.

Comment: Ah, since you put single quotes around your variable in the `grep` it is not evaluated.  Put double quotes ( " )

Comment: Just add an `echo` before `grep` and double-check what you get. Compare the output from this `echo grep '$strain_name' $BLAST_FILE` to the output from this `echo grep "$strain_name" $BLAST_FILE`. There. That’s the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: BTW, `$(pwd)` is a lot slower than `$PWD`

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, `echo` is a poor choice of tools here; `set -x` logs are much more reliable. For example, there's no difference in the output of `echo "hello" "world"` and `echo "hello world"`, even though they're very  different commands (and for things that aren't echo, the difference is generally critical).

Comment: The single quotes aside, you should avoid starting external processes from a cycle (unless it is absolutely necessary): `readarray -t strains < "${PWD}/strains_list_test" ; blast_file="${PWD}/filtered2.tsv" ; grep -E "$(IFS='|'; echo "${strains[*]//./\\.}")" < "$blast_file"`. In case the strains list is really huge, `readarray` has useful options `-c` and `-C` to split the processing into manageable chunks.

Comment: Also, as a rule, avoid `cat file | while read ...` in favor of `while read ...; done <file`; see [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) re: bugs caused by the former pattern. (And as [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) describes, `while IFS= read -r strain_name` is more robust: avoids munging data with backslashes or leading/trailing whitespace)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed, in general, but I still like `echo` as a quick and dirty hack. `set -x` is great, but mostly requires a subshell `( set -x; some_commmand; )` so that I don’t display lots of output irrelevant to the debugging task at hand.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, you can also use `{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null` to turn off `set -x` without creating extra log content or requiring a subshell. (Substitute a different file descriptor if you have `BASH_XTRACEFD` pointed somewhere other than stderr, of course)

Comment: @user21259325, ...another aside: consider using lowercase names for your own variables. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html specifies all-caps names to be used for variables meaningful to the shell and operating-system-provided tools, whereas lowercase names are "reserved for application use" and guaranteed not to have unintended side effects on POSIX-compliant tools. (Read the link keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so the same conventions apply to both types).

Comment: @Nic3500  As I have already said in my first post, I have tried double quotes instead of single quotes. Same result.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I have tried double quotes.

Comment: I've uploaded some sample code for the TSV so you can try to run it yourself. Sorry for not including that from the beginning.
I appreciate the unrelated feedback (like on faster and robuster ways to do this) but for now I need to get this basic part working, first.

Comment: I've solved the issue. The reason it wasn't working even with double quotes was the strains_list_test file. I changed the file from a vertical list to a horizontal (so only spaces separating the names, no line break) and now it works (with double quotes ofc) (though I switched to a for loop because the cat read was treating one line as a single entry while iterating).

Comment: To rephrase, I found a way to do what I wanted to do by slightly changing the input file and my way of iterating through it, but it's still not clear why the original version - WITH the double quotes - wasn't working.

Comment: That `\r` in your test output is probably a Windows-style end-of-line, which consists of two characters: `\r\n`, whereas Unix-alikes use only `\n`. See here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747722/what-is-the-difference-between-a-line-feed-and-a-carriage-return) Did you maybe create the file on Windows? If that is the problem, this post is not a duplicate of the one about double quotes.

Comment: @Cloudberry Looks like that IS the issue!
I did not create the file on Windows, but the file is a copy (that I deleted most of the contents of, to make a shorter sample dataset) of a file I received from someone else, who presumably created it on Windows. It looks like copying the file, even on a Linux system, was enough to transfer the hidden end-of-line.

I created a new file, manually typed out by hand the same names as in the other file, and with THIS version, the code works.

So yes, looks like hidden end-of-line characters as carry-over from Windows were the problem.

Comment: Addendum: Typing it out by hand was overkill, it was enough to make a new file, copy the contents of the old (Windows-created) file in the (gedit, Ubuntu-default) text editor, and that worked. Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this, Cloudberry!

Comment: Here's how to get rid of them without having to edit manually: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix)