# How to I get a text field from a database to word wrap to a specific width, while maintaining paragraph spacing?

Tags: css, asp-classic, textfield, line-spacing

I have researched this for days now and everything I have tried has failed.
I am using classic ASP and MySql database.

I am not sure where else to turn. I have read similar questions here, but the solutions did not work for me.

Any help will be most appreciated.

I tried using
`<p STYLE="word-wrap: break-word;width:200"><%=V12%></p>` and this gave me the correct wrapping, but didn't keep the paragraph spacing.

I tried using `<pre>` and this gave me the spacing, but gave me no word wrap.

I tried `V12 = Replace(INFO1("STORY_"),vbCrLf,"<BR>")` and this did nothing.

Comment: I suspect you might be trying to replace a carriage return linefeed (`VBCrLf`, or `Chr(13)`) when really it's just a linefeed (`VBLf`, or `Chr(10)`). Try replacing it with a closing and opening paragraph markup, and wrap the same markup to the DB text.  `V12 = "<p>" & Replace(INFO1("STORY_"),vblf,"</p><p>") & "</p>"`

Comment: @Adam - if that worked then you should offer it as the answer so you can be awarded some points for it.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve line breaks from a database field I used to use

```
replace(rs("myfieldname"),chr(13),"<br>")
```

However for the last few years I've been using the CSS style `white-space: pre-line`. It's client side code (obviously) so you can use it with whatever back end you have.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing `VBCrLf` when you need to be replacing `VBLf` (or ideally both).

Depending on the OS/software used to create a string, a line break can either be represented as a line feed (`VBLf` or `Chr(10)`) or a carriage return **and** a line feed (`VBCrLf` or `Chr(13)`). You can have a carriage return on it's own, but this wouldn't initiate a new line I don't think.

This answer/thread explains it well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12747850/4901783

So when replacing line breaks, you need to check for both `VBLf` and `VBCrLf`.

As for paragraph formatting, replacing a line break with `</p><p>` will close an existing paragraph and open a new one. Just as long as you also wrap the output in `p` markers too.

You could do all of this in a function, such as:

```vb
Function lb_to_p(ByVal Str)

    Str = Trim(Str)

     ' Replace all line breaks with </p><p> to indicate that the paragraph 
     ' has ended and a new one should start.

    Str = Replace(Str,VBCrLf,"</p><p>")
    Str = Replace(Str,VBCr,"</p><p>")
    Str = Replace(Str,VBLf,"</p><p>")

    ' Wrap the string in paragraph markers.

    Str = "<p>" & Str & "</p>"

    ' Remove any instances of <p></p>. This could happen if there's consecutive  
    ' line breaks, or the string starts or ends with a line break. 

    Str = Replace(Str,"<p></p>","")

    lb_to_p= Str

End Function
```