# How to split separate formulas in the same cell?

Tags: excel

I want to show three separate values derived from three separate formulas within the same cell for the purposes of my formatting.

So instead of:

```
Cell 1: 50
Cell 2: 40
Cell 3: 60
```

I want all the numbers vertically in cell 1.

```
50
40
60
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: With vba yes though you would simply be outputting the end values with carriage returns. You can't have three formulas in the same cell.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/918520/how-to-add-a-line-break-to-the-output-of-a-formula-in-excel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900916/insert-line-break-in-wrapped-cell-via-code duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line break in wrapped cell via code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900916/insert-line-break-in-wrapped-cell-via-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be semantics but if say your 'independent' formulae were:

A1: `=5*10`
A2: `=6^2+4`
A3: `=FACT(5)/2`

Then you might combine these in A1:

```
 =(5*10)&CHAR(10)&(6^2+4)&CHAR(10)&(FACT(5)/2)
```

and with wrap text enabled should achieve the result you seek.

Example with formulae from Comment (and created data):

[image]

Comment: A1: MAX($L$2:$L$15) A2: AVERAGE($L$2:$L$15) A3: MIN($L$2:$L$15) However this yields funky reults when I use it with Char(10), although the formatting is corrrect