# Excel VBA : HOW TO PRINT THE TEXT IN A CELL (like Wrap Text)

Tags: excel, vba

after running the code it is showing the text like this "AASD FDG HJK LSDH YTWIN " in a cell but i need those words in a cell wrapped
like

AASD
FDG
HJK
LSDH
YTWIN

this in one cell. what changes needs to be done to get like that for this code

```
Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "AASD FDG HJK LSDH YTWIN "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a line break in an Excel cell, use a LineFeed character. In VBA, a constant `vbLf` is defined for that. Furthermore, the cell needs to have the `WrapText`-property set.

So you can use

```
With ws.Range("E" & R) 
    .WrapText = True
    .Value = "AASD" & vbLf & "FDG" & vbLf & "HJK" & vbLF & "LSDH" & vbLF & "YTWIN"
    ' Or use
    .Value = Replace("AASD FDG HJK LSDH YTWIN ", " ", vbLf) 
end With
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900916/insert-line-break-in-wrapped-cell-via-code)

In your case, the solution would be:

```
Ws.Range("E" & R).Value = "AASD" & chr(10) & "FDG" & chr(10) & "HJK" & chr(10) & "LSDH" & chr(10) & "YTWIN "
```

As mentioned in linked post, this automatically sets WrapText to True.