VBA EXCEL procedure hangs the application
I am running a code that reads cell strings and then evaluates its width using a slightly modified solution taken from here
vb macro string width in pixel
The code does several things with the cell contents, but I manage to isolate the problem. When I run the code with, say 8000 cells, the code runs OK, and I get the width of the string in each cell and then the reminder of the code is executed. However, as the number of cells increases, the code hangs the EXCEL application. Sometimes, it manages to reach the end of the routine, but the application is already hanged, and the only solution is to kill EXCEL from Task Manager.
I believe I am having an issue with the memory, so I tried to clean up the clipboard both in the middle of the cycle (before 9000 cells, at least), but it did not help.
The computer is running Win11, Office 365+ and 16 GB of memory.
Can anyone help?
Here is the code.
'
'   For procedures
'       GetStringPixelWidth
'       GetStringPixelheight
'       GetLabelSize
'   Please see references in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012465/vb-macro-string-width-in-pixel#comment5603926_5012465
'
'API Declares
'
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, _
                                                                             ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, lpInitData As LongPtr) As LongPtr
'
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateFontIndirect Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateFontIndirectA" (lpLogFont As LOGFONT) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTextExtentPoint32 Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "GetTextExtentPoint32A" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, _
                                                                            ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal cbString As Long, lpSize As FNTSIZE) As Long
'
Private Declare PtrSafe Function MulDiv Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal nNumber As Long, ByVal nNumerator As Long, ByVal nDenominator As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hdc As LongPtr) As Long


Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90

Private Type LOGFONT
    lfHeight As Long
    lfWidth As Long
    lfEscapement As Long
    lfOrientation As Long
    lfWeight As Long
    lfItalic As Byte
    lfUnderline As Byte
    lfStrikeOut As Byte
    lfCharSet As Byte
    lfOutPrecision As Byte
    lfClipPrecision As Byte
    lfQuality As Byte
    lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
    lfFaceName As String * 32
End Type

Private Type FNTSIZE
    cx As Long
    cy As Long
End Type

Sub textsize()
'
    Dim frow As Long, lrow As Long, irow As Long, iStop As Long, columnpixels As Long
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
'
    Dim FontName As String
    Dim FontSize As Single
    Dim FontBold As Boolean
    Dim sText As String
    Dim stringWidth As Single
'
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    frow = 4
    lrow = 11701
    'lrow = 9000
'
    FontName = "Verdana"
    FontSize = 11
    FontBold = False
'
'
    For irow = frow To lrow
'
        Set rng = Range("A" & irow & ":D" & irow)
        Set cell = Range("B" & irow)
        
        With cell
            If .Value2 <> "" Then
'
                With .font
                    If .Name <> FontName Then rng.font.Name = FontName
                    If .Size <> FontSize Then rng.font.Size = FontSize
                    If (.Bold) Then
                        If Len(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value2) = 4 Then
                            FontBold = True
                            rng.font.Bold = True
                        Else
                            FontBold = False
                            rng.font.Bold = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
'
                sText = .Value2
'                                                               '
                stringWidth = GetStringPixelWidth(sText, FontName, FontSize, FontBold)
'
            End If
        End With
        Debug.Print irow, stringWidth
    Next irow
'
    DoEvents
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Call ClearClipboard
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
End Sub
'

Public Function ClearClipboard()
  OpenClipboard (0&)
  EmptyClipboard
  CloseClipboard
End Function
'
'
Public Function GetStringPixelWidth(text As String, FontName As String, FontSize As Single, _
                                    Optional isBold As Boolean = False, Optional isItalics As Boolean = False) As Integer

    Dim font As New StdFont
    Dim sz As FNTSIZE
    font.Name = FontName
    font.Size = FontSize
    font.Bold = isBold
    font.Italic = isItalics

    sz = GetLabelSize(text, font)
    GetStringPixelWidth = sz.cx

End Function
'
'
Public Function GetStringPixelHeight(text As String, FontName As String, FontSize As Single, _
                                     Optional isBold As Boolean = False, Optional isItalics As Boolean = False) As Integer
'
    Dim font As New StdFont
    Dim sz As FNTSIZE
    font.Name = FontName
    font.Size = FontSize
    font.Bold = isBold
    font.Italic = isItalics
    
    sz = GetLabelSize(text, font)
    GetStringPixelHeight = sz.cy

End Function
'
'
Private Function GetLabelSize(text As String, font As StdFont) As FNTSIZE
    Dim tempDC As LongPtr
    Dim tempBMP As LongPtr, oldBMP As LongPtr
    Dim F As LongPtr, oldF As LongPtr, trash As LongPtr
    Dim lf As LOGFONT
    Dim textsize As FNTSIZE

    ' Create a device context and a bitmap that can be used to store a
    ' temporary font object
    tempDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0)
    tempBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(tempDC, 1, 1)
    '
    ' Saves the device's default BitMap
    oldBMP = SelectObject(tempDC, tempBMP)
    '
    ' Assign the bitmap to the device context
    'DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, tempBMP)

    ' Set up the LOGFONT structure and create the font
    lf.lfFaceName = font.Name & Chr$(0)
    '
    Dim TempDC2 As LongPtr
    TempDC2 = GetDC(0)
    '
    lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(font.Size, GetDeviceCaps(TempDC2, LOGPIXELSY), 72) 'LOGPIXELSY=90
    lf.lfItalic = font.Italic
    lf.lfStrikeOut = font.Strikethrough
    lf.lfUnderline = font.Underline
    If font.Bold Then lf.lfWeight = 800 Else lf.lfWeight = 400
    F = CreateFontIndirect(lf)
    '
    'Saves the device's default Font
    oldF = SelectObject(tempDC, F)
    '
    ' Assign the font to the device context
    'DeleteObject SelectObject(tempDC, F)

    ' Measure the text, and return it into the textSize SIZE structure
    GetTextExtentPoint32 tempDC, text, Len(text), textsize

    ' Clean up (very important to avoid memory leaks!)
    ' Restores the original Font and BitMap,
    ' and then deletes those created by the routine
    trash = SelectObject(tempDC, oldF)
    trash = SelectObject(tempDC, oldBMP)
    '
    DeleteObject F
    DeleteObject tempBMP
    DeleteDC tempDC
    'DeleteDC TempDC2
    ReleaseDC 0, TempDC2
  '
  ' Return the measurements
    GetLabelSize = textsize

End Function```


You have seemingly randomly replaced some Longs with LongPtrs, replacing some that should have stayed Long, and missing some that should have become LongPtr. You should have not done that.

Thank you very much GSerg. I think I managed to correct all statements, as shown in the edited post.
Unfortunately, the problem is still there. The only way to keep the work done by the procedure is to force “save and close” the current workbook, but the application refuses to quit via VBA. I had to quit manually.
I guess that if I had more rows than the 11700, the program would hang anyway.

Clean up (very important to avoid memory leaks!) - except that you are deleting your objects while they are still selected in the DC, which you shouldn't do, so it probably fails. And you shouldn't be deleting the stock bitmap and font that the DC came with, although it's safe to do that. You should select the original bitmap/font back into the DC, then delete your ones.

See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130306-00/?p=5043.

Thanks again for your valuable corrections, GSerg. I think I did all the corrections you pointed out: I saved the device's default objects, I did not deleted them, and at the end I restored them, and thereafter I deleted my own objects (see amended code). However,   I still get the same result: the apllication hangs.

The first problem is that you are never using TempDC2, instead you are calling GetDC again. You are also deleting the TempDC2 when you should ReleaseDC it. So replace the GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), LOGPIXELSY) with GetDeviceCaps(TempDC2, LOGPIXELSY), and DeleteDC TempDC2 with ReleaseDC 0, TempDC2. The second problem is that oldBMP = SelectObject(tempDC, tempBMP) fails to select the bitmap, although that does not affect your ability to delete it later. That must be because you should be using CreateCompatibleDC instead of CreateDC (compatible with TempDC2!).

I have no words for your patience, RSerg. I implemented the first part of your last comment, and the application finally ran smoothly. However, I did not understand the second part. It is true that with the code as is, the oldBMP variable is 0^. However, I did not manage to correct the issue; when I replaced CreateDC by CreateCompatibleDC (and DeleteDC TempDC  by ReleaseDC 0, TempDC), I got a non-zero value for `oldBPM, but the program hangèd again. I am fine now with the first corrections, but I would like to understand what you meant with the second part of your previous reply.

Somewhat non-intuitively, the bitmap you create with CreateCompatibleBitmap is not compatible with the DC you create with CreateDC, so SelectObject fails to select that bitmap into that DC (and the fact that the code still works means you didn't need to do that anyway). That bitmap however would be compatible with a DC created by CreateCompatibleDC(TempDC2), that's what I was talking about. You should have not replaced DeleteDC TempDC with ReleaseDC 0, TempDC though, you should have replaced DeleteDC TempDC2 with ReleaseDC 0, TempDC2.

Thank you for the explanation. I have now the application runnig with no issues. Thank you again for saving me.
